# How to mock ControlContainer in angular unit test?

Tags: angular, angular-test

How can I mock a `ControlContainer` instance so that I can test my component?

I have a child component that injects a `ControlContainer` into the constructor, so its usage is

```
<acr-score-card formGroupName="score"></acr-score-card>
```

and the component itself is

```
@Component({
  selector: 'acr-score-card',
  templateUrl: './score-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./score-card.component.scss']
})
export class ScoreCardComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private ngControl: ControlContainer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = <FormGroup>this.ngControl.control;
  }

  ...

}
```

Everything works fine when I run in the browser but I cannot get the unit tests to work as I am not sure how to mock the `ControlContainer` instance in order to setup the provider, this is the contents of my spec file:

```
describe('ScoreCardComponent', () => {
  let component: ScoreCardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ScoreCardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [TestingModule],
      declarations: [ScoreCardComponent],
      providers: [/** what goes here to mock the ControlContainer */]
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ScoreCardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

So, to repeat the question, how can I mock a `ControlContainer` instance so that I can test my component?

Comment: Can you check this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/06045271991fb36d3d5ed631564717664647eefa/packages/core/test/render3/di_spec.ts#L1307)? It shows a way inject COntrolContainers. But since `ControlContainer` is an interface, you need create instance with the classes that implement the interface like `FormGroupDirective` etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks to @KiraAG for comment and was able to work out what was required from provided link, so posting answer here in case anyone else comes across this question

So in your test you need to `provide` the `ControlContainer` instance in your test module, this is basically going to be either a `FormGroupDirective` or a `FormControlDirective` depending on what you expect to be passed to your component.

For example, in your test file create the `FormGroup` that represents the part of the form you are using

```
const fg: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  'answer': new FormControl(''),
  ...
});
```

Next create a `FormGroupDirective` and set the `form` property to the `FormGroup` created above

```
const fgd: FormGroupDirective = new FormGroupDirective([], []);
fgd.form = fg;
```

Now in you test module setup you can provide the `ControlContainer`

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [TestingModule],
      declarations: [ScoreCardComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: ControlContainer, useValue: fgd }
      ]
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

And that's it, the constructor injection is satisfied.

Comment: I am followed this, but getting Error: No provider for FormGroupDirective!

Comment: I get the following error: 'Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute any' thoughts?

Comment: I inherited this code ... this.scheduleFormGroup = this.controlContainer.control.get('schedule'); ... so I had to wrap it like this ... const schedule: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  schedule: new FormGroup({
    minute: new FormControl('*/5'),
    hour: new FormControl('*'),
    date: new FormControl('*'),
    month: new FormControl('*'),
    day: new FormControl('*'),
    active: new FormControl(false)
  })
});

Comment: @RebeccaDouglas
I had the same problem initially.
In my components I have an input `[controlName]` that is used to get the control from the ControlContainer that is injected.
When I passed that `fixture.component.controlName = 'theName'` my spec worked.

Comment: BTW: I was googling for this solution several times unsuccesfully, and now I realize this was here all the time since early 2019.
But finally the needed solution is found. Thx allot @neil-stevens 

Answer (score 5):

I used Neil Stevens's answer.

But I had

```
viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective}],
```

in the component.

So in tests I have to use

```
providers: [{provide: FormGroupDirective, useValue: fgd}],
```

Maybe this will help someone.